Opening android app trough deeplinks on Meta platforms
I have several deeplinks configured for my android app. They work like expected when clicking on them from an email, SMS, note and chrome browser etc. However I am unable to get the deeplinks working inside the Meta Platform (e.g. Instagram, Facebook).
I am trying the following scenarios:

Opening my app trough an Instagram profile with a deeplinked url.

This results in the url being opened inside their browser instead of the intended app. 


Using their browser as step in between e.g. using a linktree with the deeplinked url as an option which is clickable.

This results in their browser opening the url, staying inside the browser. Not opening the app as expected.



However when inside their browser you are able to open the website inside a chrome browser (trough the kebab menu, top right), when doing so the app suddenly does open!
This makes me believe Meta is blocking deeplinks on purpose, which i cannot find any documentation or references about. This behavior can also be reproduced by using https://youtube.com as deeplink for example, opening the youtube app or it being opened inside the meta browser.
Hope someone can enlighten me on this behavior and if it is even possible to use deeplinks on their platform and/or their browser?.
